# $1/N$ expansion in $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills theories at large $N$

Tags: yang-mills, large-n

It is a well-known fact that correlators of $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills theories at large $N$ are expanded in powers of the 't Hooft coupling $g_{YM}^{2}N$ and $1/N$.

Is there a reason why an expansion in powers of $g_{YM}$ and $1/N$ is not feasible?

Comment: correlators are **not** expanded in powers of the 't Hooft coupling - this parameter need not be small.

Comment: Ok, let me get this straight. All those questions... Are you trying to win some badge? To earn reputation? Because otherwise you either try to learn the material way over your head or do too little thinking by yourself.

Comment: @ OON. Thank you for the comment. I apologise - I have already once been told this by ACuriousMind. I will think carefully before I ask a question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}$
It's got to do with the fact that the double series expansion in each of these parameters really amounts to a single expansion of the theory in $1/N$. Let's look at large $N$ QCD (i.e. Yang-Mills with Dirac fermions) as an example. Without worrying about gauge fixing and all that, the path integral for the theory has the form $$\int{\exp\bigg(-\frac{i}{4g^2}\int{F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}d^4x}  +i\int{\bar\psi(i\gamma^{\mu}D_\mu-m)\psi d^4x}\bigg)}\cal{D}AD\bar\psi D\psi$$
Say we want to integrate out the fermions. This just gives us a functional determinant, which when rewritten as a tracelog gives us the expression $$\int{\exp\bigg(-\frac{i}{4g^2}\int{F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}d^4x}  +N\Tr\log(i\gamma^{\mu}D_\mu-m)\bigg)}\cal{D}A$$ We can now write $$\int{\exp\bigg(-N\bigg[\frac{i}{4g^2N}\int{F_{\mu\nu}^{a}F^{a\mu\nu}d^4x}  -\Tr\log(i\gamma^{\mu}D_\mu-m)\bigg]\bigg)}\cal{D}A$$ This allows us to evaluate the integral in the $N\rightarrow\infty$ limit as a stationary phase approximation with effective coupling $g^2N$. Hope this helped!

Edit: I should point out that the Yang-Mills coupling isn't really an expansion parameter in the large $N$ scheme, the "color" number $1/N$ is. This is what is essential for its use in nonperturbative analysis. However, the above manipulation shows that in order to extract the appropriate powers of $N$ from the original perturbative diagrammatic expansion in the double-line formalism, you need to put an extra power of $N$ with the coupling.

Edit again: This argument should not be taken too seriously, as there are additional factors of N in the pure gauge term which arise from the appearance of the coupling. It is possible to reconcile this problem in certain cases by making a clever choice of gauge (lightcone gauge in 2 dimensions, for example).

Comment: I'm not sure about this argument. $F^2$ and $Tr(D)$ contain hidden factors of N.

Comment: It's a rather standard argument. This argument applied to d=2 is how 't Hooft solved large N QCD

Comment: Your confusion may come from the notation being a bit schematic. You have to do some standard tricks with gamma matrices and whatnot to make sense of the covariant derivative tracelog, but it ends up coming out with just a power of N in front. It's easy to see this because the functional trace "factors" into the trace over the representation and a standard functional trace

Comment: Just look at the pure gauge part. If what you say is true, then the large N expansion is the same as the ordinary perturbative expansion

Comment: Part of the procedure of large N is to rescale the coupling. I left a power of N with the coupling explicit in order to make more direct contact with OP's notation. The large N expansion is not equivalent to ordinary perturbation theory because you hold the rescaled coupling fixed.

Comment: You write $1/g^2=N[1/(Ng^2)]$, so the large $N$ expansion at fixed $\lambda$ is the same as small $g$ expansion. This is presumably not what we want(?)

Comment: Consult any reference on large N as given through stationary phase. Even in non-gauge theories such as the Gross-Neveu model, couplings are always rescaled to match the appropriate power of N. The coupling runs according to the RG anyway, so you can't take its formal appearance in the Lagrangian too seriously.

Comment: Yes, you rescale the coupling. But you also have to do a little extra work to get the genus expansion, because as written you have not identified all factors of $N$, and you have not reorganized the ordinary perturbative expansion.

Comment: The reorganization comes from all of the fermion diagrams included in the tracelog.

Comment: But the pure gauge theory already has a non-trivial large N expansion (the genus expansion).

Comment: I see your concern now. F^2 contains more powers of the coupling, which are also scaled. My point in this outline was just to answer OP's question on why $g^2N$ was the natural parameter. I should point out that this argument does work if you choose the gauge appropriately, but it is not the most general possible.